# Python - Exclude weekends between two Dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between the two dates but want to exclude the weekends from it . Below is the format of dates :

```
CreateDate  - 2017-08-29 10:47:00
ResolveDate - 2017-09-23 16:56:00
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**numpy.busday_count:**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html)

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

create_date = "2017-08-29 10:47:00"
resolve_date = "2017-09-23 16:56:00"

create_datetime = datetime.strptime(create_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
resolve_datetime = datetime.strptime(resolve_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(f"The difference in days is: {(resolve_datetime - create_datetime).days}")
print(f"The difference in business days is: {np.busday_count(create_datetime.date(), resolve_datetime.date())}")
```

**Output:**

```
The difference in days is: 25
The difference in business days is: 19
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution but how can we get the exact fractional values? ( Including hours as well ?)

Answer (score 4):

One more python way using isoweekday():

```
import datetime, pprint

# isoweekday: Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7
start_date = datetime.date(2017, 10, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2017, 12, 31)
days = end_date - start_date
valid_date_list = {(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
                        for x in range(days.days+1)
                        if (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).isoweekday() <= 5
                       }
print("Business Days = {}".format(len(valid_date_list)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Run a `while` loop that keeps adding a `timedelta` of +1 day to `create_date`. Keep track of weekday vs. weekend in a separate counter.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea with `weekday()` but as a one-line function:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def get_business_days(start_date, end_date):
    return sum([
        (start_date + timedelta(days=i)).weekday() not in (5, 6)
        for i in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)
    ])


create_date = "2017-08-29 10:47:00"
resolve_date = "2017-09-23 16:56:00"

s = datetime.strptime(create_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
e = datetime.strptime(resolve_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(get_business_days(s, e))
```

Answer (score -1):

With `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-29 10:47:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-09-23 16:56:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
delta = (d2 - d1).days
diff_weekdays = delta - (delta // 7) * 2

print(diff_weekdays)    # 19
```

Comment: How can i get exact hours diff from this (excluding weekend days and holidays )

Comment: This solution doesn't work as expected, because it assumes the start date is at the beginning of the week. If the start date is e.g. this friday, and the end date is the next monday, the result will be 3, because of the way transcurred weeks are calculated (3 // 7 = 0).