# Exclude weekends /holidays for calculating the time hour difference in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

here a some solutions around to calculate the day difference in python with excluding none business days (german business days):

[Python - Exclude weekends between two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386764/python-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates)

[Calculate difference between two dates excluding weekends in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194543/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-in-python)

But how can I apply this on a pandas dataframe, when I want to have the difference in hours and not in days?

When I try:

```
df['Diff'] = np.busday_count(df['end'], df['start'])
```

I receive the error:

> TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('

So my target is to calculate:

```
start                end
2019-01-01 08:00:00  2019-01-08 08:00:00
```

Should lead to: `df['Diff'] = 5*24 = 100`

Comment: Do you need explude weekends or bussines days?

Comment: I need business days, so weekends and holidays should be excludes, based on germany (for example christmas)

Comment: Ok, please check dupe, if some problem let me know

Comment: I will check the answer, it will be some pain, thx

Comment: I think dupe answer was pain for creating for me. ;)

Comment: It is crazy that there is no shortcut from pandas to it...

Comment: I found a different work around, but it was also a pain ...