# How to retrieve the date from today excluding weekends with datetime or pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to create a function that takes in a number and returns the {number} days prior to today, excluding weekends.

For example,

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_date(days = 5):
    today = date.today()
    return today - timedelta(days)
```

when today is 2020-06-11, it should output 2020-06-04 (excluding 06-06 and 06-07).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Exclude weekends between two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386764/python-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only Python's built-in libraries:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_date(days = 5):
    today = date.today()
    if days == 0:
        return today

    retval = today
    while days > 0:
        retval -= timedelta(days=1)
        if retval.weekday() not in [5,6]:
            days -= 1
    return retval
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `BDay`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

pd.to_datetime('2020-06-11')-BDay(5)

#Timestamp('2020-06-04 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_offset.html

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
days = -5
np.busday_offset(today,days)
```

Comment: Your solution works well, but is there a way to convert it into a datetime object?

Comment: of course, sorry, I have not though to provide it 
```x = np.busday_offset(today,days); converted=x.astype('O')```
or simply ```str(x)``` or ```x.astype(datetime)``` 
see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html and SO has many answers about this conversion .. I also usually inspect interactively the advertised methods and attributes of the object by ```dir(x)``` in ipython to see some info if the class is new to me and I am too lazy to search the api documentation.

Comment: and here is a full blown discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64